# IQKeyboardManager with UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, iqkeyboardmanager

I've implemented the [**IQKeyboardManager framework**](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) to make the keyboard handle easier. It works very fine, except for one thing :

There're some `UItextField` controls in my app which open a `UIDatePicker` in place of a default keyboard (e.g. number pad, decimal pad, ASCII capable, etc.).

Here's a code sample with the graphical result :

```
// Create the datePicker
UIDatePicker *birthdayDatePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
[birthdayDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

// Assign the datePicker to the textField
[myTextField setInputView:birthdayDatePicker];
```

**My question is :**
Is it possible to handle the action on the *"OK"* button to fill the field *"Date de naissance"* ?

[image]

## EDIT :

For the ones who want to know how I solved my problem :

- in my **.h**, I imported `IQDropDownTextField.h` :

  ```
  #import "IQDropDownTextField.h"
  ```
- in the **.h**, I changed the type of my `UITextField` to `IQDropDownTextField` :

  ```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet IQDropDownTextField *myTextField;
  ```
- select your field in Interface Builder or in your .xib, and show the Identity Inspector : change your field's class to `IQDropDownTextField`.

### *Note according to **Mohd Iftekhar Qurashi** comment : the two next points can be avoided with the following code :*

```
// Set myTextField's dropDownMode to IQDropDownModeDatePicker
myTextField.dropDownMode = IQDropDownModeDatePicker;

// Create a dateFormatter
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

// Assign the previously created dateFormatter to myTextField
myTextField.dateFormatter = df;

// Assign a minimum date and/or maximum date if you want
myTextField.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
myTextField.maximumDate = [NSDate date];

// That's all !
```

- in the **.m**, I added the `setCustomDoneTarget:action:` method :

  ```
  // Create the datePicker
  UIDatePicker *birthdayDatePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
  [birthdayDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

  // Assign the datePicker to the textField
  [myTextField setInputView:birthdayDatePicker];

  // Just added this line
  [myTextField setCustomDoneTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];
  ```
- in the **.m**, I added the `doneAction:` method :

  ```
  - (void)doneAction:(UITextField *)textField
  {
      [myTextField setText:[DateHelper getStringFromDate:birthdayDatePicker.date format:@"dd/MM/yyyy" useGmt:NO]]; // getStringFromDate:format:useGmt: is a method to convert a NSDate to a NSString according to the date format I want
  }
  ```

Comment: FYI, IQDropDownTextField have property to set it's 'IQDropDownMode', you can directly set it's mode to 'IQDropDownModeDatePicker' to show datePicker as inputView. No need to maintain datePicker manually, get the selected date from 'date' property.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi Thanks for the information, I missed it. It saves me a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now add customised selector(please refer `'IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.h'`) for `previous/next/done` to get notify. Note that custom selector doesn't affect the native functionality of `previous/next/done`, it's just used for callback purpose only. For detail documentation please refer `'IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.h'`, for 'how to use?' please refer '`TextFieldViewController.m`'.

Comment: Is the Pod updated ? I ran a `pod update` but I don't get your updates in your latest commit (the `setCustomDoneTarget:action:` method for example).

Comment: I've implemented these selector yesterday and pod is not updated yet, but the github repo is updated.

Comment: OK. Anyway thank you for your fastly implementation ! Very great framework.